# OWL API Silent Imports

Tags: owl-api

I unable to load an ontology using the OWL API because it is missing some imports. I am "silent"cing the imports using `OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration` but i am still getting errors.

**My code:**

```
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
            //set silent imports
            OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration config = new OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration();
            config.setMissingImportHandlingStrategy(MissingImportHandlingStrategy.SILENT);
            manager.setOntologyLoaderConfiguration(config);
File f = new File(path);
        OWLOntology o = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(f);
```

**Errors:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.UnloadableImportException: Could not load imported ontology: <https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/pep/> Cause: https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/pep/
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.makeLoadImportRequest(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1605)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.TripleHandlers$TPImportsHandler.handleTriple(TripleHandlers.java:1568)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.TripleHandlers$HandlerAccessor.handleStreaming(TripleHandlers.java:200)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.OWLRDFConsumer.statementWithResourceValue(OWLRDFConsumer.java:1507)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.statementWithResourceValue(RDFParser.java:365)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.EmptyPropertyElement.startElement(StartRDF.java:253)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.PropertyElementList.startElement(StartRDF.java:692)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.startElement(RDFParser.java:196)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:140)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:73)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:212)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1035)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:947)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadImports(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1563)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.makeLoadImportRequest(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1599)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.TripleHandlers$TPImportsHandler.handleTriple(TripleHandlers.java:1568)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.TripleHandlers$HandlerAccessor.handleStreaming(TripleHandlers.java:200)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.OWLRDFConsumer.statementWithResourceValue(OWLRDFConsumer.java:1507)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.statementWithResourceValue(RDFParser.java:365)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.EmptyPropertyElement.startElement(StartRDF.java:253)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.PropertyElementList.startElement(StartRDF.java:692)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.startElement(RDFParser.java:196)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:140)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:73)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:212)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1035)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:947)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:903)
    at aml.ontology.Ontology.<init>(Ontology.java:170)
    at aml.Main.main(Main.java:87)
Caused by: org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLOntologyCreationIOException: https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/pep/
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1035)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:947)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadImports(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1563)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.makeLoadImportRequest(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1599)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/pep/
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1939)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1938)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.AbstractOWLParser.getInputStreamFromContentEncoding(AbstractOWLParser.java:167)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.AbstractOWLParser.getInputStream(AbstractOWLParser.java:127)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.AbstractOWLParser.getInputSource(AbstractOWLParser.java:234)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:72)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:212)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/pep/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.AbstractOWLParser.getInputStream(AbstractOWLParser.java:103)
    ... 62 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration` class uses (like most of OWL API) a defensive copying pattern, so when you call a setter (like `setMissingImportHandlingStrategy`), it copies the current configuration and sets the strategy on the copy which it then returns (basically a defensively copying Builder pattern). Therefore, you would have to pass this copied config to `OWLOntologyManager` as follows:

```java
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

//set silent imports
OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration config = new OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration();
config = config.setMissingImportHandlingStrategy(MissingImportHandlingStrategy.SILENT);
manager.setOntologyLoaderConfiguration(config);
```

Another option would be to set it directly on the default loader configuration present in the `OWLOntologyManager` instance as in (this is how I do it my project):

```java
manager.getOntologyConfigurator().setMissingImportHandlingStrategy(MissingImportHandlingStrategy.SILENT);
```